# Save image path to database and drawable to internal storage

Tags: android, image, sqlite, imageview, storage

I have an image view, when I click on it, I choose an image with the image picker, how can I save the resource name to the phone's internal database and the image to the internal storage? What will the database handler and my object class have as a variable, a string?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you mean by

> phone's internal database

your custom SQLiteDatabase it would be a String and what datatype at your object class depends upon what you want to do with that image. Without further information a String or Bitmap as the type of your variable should cover most of your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a folder and copy the image, and save the route on your local database